# How do I manually input the user agent in the Opera browser?

Tags: configuration, opera, user-agent

Where is the configuration for user agent, what file and where?

For version 11, in `opera:config` I can only pick from some preset browsers, but I want to use something else so I guess I have to manually change the configuration but I don't know where it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can only add text here:

*Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; **String**; en)*

http://www.opera.com/support/usingopera/operaini/#isp

Comment: Well, this is the closest thing to changing a part of the user agent from within opera but I would have wanted to change the whole thing from within a file. It has to be stored somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Opera Dragonfly](http://my.opera.com/dragonfly/blog/) to replace the User-Agent header while debugging. With a User JavaScript you can also replace `navigator.userAgent` and friends.